# How can I access Laravel config data within the config directory?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This may sound odd but I have placed a new config file within `app/config` simply called `config.php`. My aim is to allow a user to only have to modify that file. What I am trying to do is link it with the other config files within the directory.

I have tried `config::get('config.key')` etc, and well that didn't work... I was shown `class not found`. Then I tried `self::get('config.key')` and that said it can't find the file.

So I was wondering if this is possible how can I achieve it?

**EDIT**

I wrote `config` when it should be `Config`

Haha, well that wasted time :p

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Simply register a new class?

Comment: @baao When outside the config folder, you can call config data like: `config::get('database.connections.mysql.database')` and so on. How can I do this, but from inside the config folder? I have a file called config.php within `app/config`. So how can I access data in there from say, the database.php file?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt what you said doesn't work. but you can try this one.
    require app_path().'/start/config.php';